# Whenever I pass the value of a string list I'm getting an error

Tags: kotlin

```
fun sayHello(greet:String,itemsToGreet:List<String>){
    itemsToGreet.forEach { itemsToGreet ->
        println("$greet, $itemsToGreet")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val interestingThings = listOf("kotlin","program","comic")
    sayHello(greet="hi", interestingThings)
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help with an error without seeing the original error message.  Please edit your post to include the exact wording of any error messages, including the full [stack trace](/a/23353174) of any exceptions, if applicable, as well as which line of code the stack trace points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of problems:

- You can't mix *named* and *positional* arguments in a method call. This results in a compilation error.
- While not explicitly wrong, the fact that you're shadowing the `itemsToGreet` variable in your lambda expression is a code smell.

This fixes both:

```
fun sayHello(greet:String,itemsToGreet:List<String>) {
    itemsToGreet.forEach { item ->                        // new variable name
        println("$greet, $item")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val interestingThings = listOf("kotlin", "program", "comic")

    sayHello("hi", interestingThings)                     // positional arguments
    sayHello(greet="hi", itemsToGreet=interestingThings)  // named arguments
}
```